# Where did Brooklyn Nine-Nine get Boyle's lookalike?

Tags: casting, brooklyn-nine-nine

The character Bill (played by Winston Story) really does have an uncanny resemblance to Charles Boyle (played by Joe Lo Truglio). I know that the Brooklyn Nine-Nine production do sometimes work off-set truths into the show (such as [Terry Crews' real love of yogurt](http://thesource.com/2014/11/09/exclusive-terry-crews-talks-brooklyn-nine-nine-more/) or [Stephanie Beatriz's bisexuality](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.vulture.com/amp/2018/05/stephanie-beatriz-bisexual-awakening-on-screen-and-off.html)), and I wondered if Winston served as a stunt double for Joe and they decided to incorporate the resemblance into episodes for humorous effect.

**Was Winston involved with the show before he was cast as Boyle's lookalike, Bill, or is the likeness more of a coincidence?**

Comment: Boyle himself sees no resemblance in Bill, who are we to judge? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no official sources for this, but from my understanding, Winston Story was specifically cast because of his resemblance to Joe Lo Truglio.

There was no coincidence, he was **chosen** to play a Boyle doppelganger.

Comment: I'll give the question a bit longer to see if anyone comes up with anything, but I thought this might be the case. +1 and I'll accept after some more time passes.

Comment: @Nemon27 I agree, I searched a lot to see if I could find something related, but couldn't find anything, maybe someone else has better luck :)